# trying to determine best user interface for layouts - winform button that shows dropdown

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I am adding layout management to my winforms GUI which really just means that you can "Save" the current column settings with a "Key"

so for example you can have "View 1" or "View 2".

anyway, i dont have much real estate on the screen but i am trying to figure out the best way to:

1. Allow you to save the current layout as a "Saved Layout"
2. Allow you to select another layout and apply it.

Right now i have:

1. Save Icon
2. Combobox that has a list of saved layouts
3. Apply Icon

It works ok but it look a little unclear because the dropdown combobox is available and doesn't necessarly correspond to the view you are looking at.

I thought one idea was to instead of showing the combo, to just have two buttons:

1. Save layout
2. Apply existing layout.

when you clicked #2, this would then turn into a dropdown and show the other layouts.

thoughts or any other suggestions on a clear way to visualize this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When space is tight, I'm a big fan of the LinkLabel and the ContextMenuStrip controls.

`Save` would pop up another form or something for entering the name of the current layout (or this could be set automatically), and `Load` displays the saved layouts in a popup menu that can then be clicked to select the desired layout.

LinkLabels take up less room than Buttons and ComboBoxes, and there's never any confusion about how they work.

Comment: I had to remove the image from your post because ImageShack has deleted it and replaced it with advertising. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/263771/215468 for more information. If possible, it would be great for you to re-upload them. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I like your second idea, with one button to save and one generating a dropdown + apply

from my experience it's sometimes better to separate such logic into own modal window to select what to do and near your layout would be an icon suggesting for "advanced usage"

always try to "comment around" the components (use hints as much as possible) to tell the user what can be done with specific functionality

[alt text http://www.talkingtext.com/wordpress_en/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/googleproduct.jpg](http://www.talkingtext.com/wordpress_en/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/googleproduct.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

I try to keep the UI as uncluttered as I can, particularly when it comes to functionality that is of a more ancillary nature.  To that end, if I can utilize something like a context menu that the user can right-click to pull up, I will.  From the context menu, I generally provide a dialog box to support the functionality needed.

If the saving of the layout is a primary function of the form you are displaying to the user, it might warrant UI elements like a button or combo box that has dedicated real estate.  Otherwise, I'd think seriously about putting the controls that provide that functionality on another pop-up dialog and using a mechanism like a context menu to bring up that dialog.

The downside to the context menu idea, initially, is that the user needs to "know" that the functionality exists.  That might be solved by training or by tooltip hints or other means.  Typically once the user "knows" that controls like ListViews, TreeViews and DataGridViews can have context menus, they don't have problems finding the functionality.

Just my two cents.